# How to get all NSRange of a particular character in a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

I have two NSStrings: `orgText` and `searchLetter`.
I want to highlight every occurrences of the searchLetter in the `orgText` with a red color.
How can I get the `NSRange` of all occurrences of the `searchLetter` ?
for eg :

```
suppose: orgText = "abcahaiapaoiuiapplma"
         searchLetter = "a".
```

I want to hightlight all "a" occurrences in "abcahaiapaoiuiapplma" with red color.
Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I wrote this method for my project - [SUITextView with highlight](https://github.com/sakrist/SUITextView):

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString*) setColor:(UIColor*)color word:(NSString*)word inText:(NSMutableAttributedString*)mutableAttributedString {

    NSUInteger count = 0, length = [mutableAttributedString length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);

    while(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:word options:0 range:range];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
            [mutableAttributedString setTextColor:color range:NSMakeRange(range.location, [word length])];
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
            count++; 
        }
    }

    return mutableAttributedString;
}
```

And in my category of NSMutableAttributedString:

```
- (void) setTextColor:(UIColor*)color range:(NSRange)range {
    // kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
    [self removeAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName range:range]; // Work around for Apple leak
    [self addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)color.CGColor range:range];
}
```

Comment: I think there's an extra "}" floating around, but working great still in '14

Comment: @dacopenhagen you are right. that method was written for multiple words :)

Comment: What's the point of count? To see how many occurrences you've replaced while debugging?

Comment: For me (iOS 7) it only worked with other kinds of arguments in that category method. `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` instead of `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` and a `UIColor` object instead of its `CGColor` property.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not seeing any solution with regular expression, so I've created an elegant one, it may be useful for someone in the future.

```
- (BOOL)highlightString:(NSString *)string inText:(NSMutableAttributedString *)attributedString withColour:(UIColor *)color {
    NSError *_error;
    NSRegularExpression *_regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:string options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&_error];
    if (_error == nil) {
        [_regexp enumerateMatchesInString:attributedString.string options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.string.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
            if (result.numberOfRanges > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.numberOfRanges; i++) {
                    [attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:color range:[result rangeAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }
        }];
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code crash at "setTextColor" for MutableAttributeString

instead of it use below code

```
NSDictionary *tempdict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0],NSFontAttributeName,color,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[mutableAttributedString setAttributes:tempdict range:NSMakeRange(range.location, [word length])];
```

Answer (score -1):

this is an easier way of doing it

```
NSString *str = @"hello world";
NSMutableAttributedString *attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
[attr addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]} 
              range:[str rangeOfString:@"world"]];
```

Comment: NOTE:this would only add attributes to the first substring occurrence