# Applying Text Attributes to ALL Occurrence of certain string

Tags: ios, string, swift

Im applying a text attribute the `string` "Updated - ".

```
var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
             let rangeOfString = (textView.text as NSString).rangeOfString("Updated - ")
             attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(8.0)],range: rangeOfString)
             textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

I want this to apply to **all** occurences of the `string` rather than just the one

Tried

```
var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
             let stringRange = (textView.text as NSString).rangeOfString("Updated - ")


             if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {

                    attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(8.0)],range: stringRange)
                    textView.attributedText = attributedText

            }
```

This still only applies the attributed text to one occurrence of the `string`

Similar question  [Color all occurrences of string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180184/color-all-occurrences-of-string-in-swift)

Update

```
var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
             var inputLength = count(attributedText.string)
             let stringRange = "Updated - "

             var searchLength = count(stringRange)
             var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length)

             while (range.location != NSNotFound) {

                range = (attributedText.string as NSString).rangeOfString("Updated - ", options: nil, range: range)

                if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                     attributedText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(8.0), range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
                    range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
                }
             }

 textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop through all instances of "Updated - " within your text and grab their range. One way to do this is like so (tailored to your problem from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180184/color-all-occurrences-of-string-in-swift)):

```
var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)

while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    range = (attributedText.string as NSString).rangeOfString("Updated - ", options: nil, range: range)
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
         attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(8.0)],range: range)
        range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
    }
}

textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

Comment: Updated, still not working as expected, no attribution now

Comment: @JSA986 you have to set the attributedTex attribute on the textView. Also I updated the .addAttribute to match your desired effect. This should work now.

Comment: Still the same, text is not attributed at all `-[UICTFont set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: @JSA986 I think there was an error in .addAttributes. I corrected it I believe. Give it a try.

Comment: Awesome thats it, thanks for your assistance, plus 1!

Answer (score 3):

Here code that returns an array of ranges of occurrences of the string. I used JustAnotherCoder's code. Then you can loop over the ranges. I just generalized the code for other uses.

> Swift 3

```
func rangesOf(subString: String) -> [NSRange] {
    var ranges = [NSRange]()

    var range: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)
    while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        range = (self as NSString).range(of: subString, options: .caseInsensitive, range: range)
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            ranges.append(range)
            range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: self.characters.count - (range.location + range.length))
        }
    }
    return ranges
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated @Khaled Annajar's answer for **Swift 4** utilizing String Extension:

```
extension String {

    func ranges(subString: String) -> [NSRange] {
        var ranges = [NSRange]()
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: count)
        while range.location != NSNotFound {
            range = (self as NSString).range(of: subString, options: .caseInsensitive, range: range)
            if range.location != NSNotFound {
                ranges.append(range)
                range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length,
                            length: count - (range.location + range.length))
            }
        }
        return ranges
    }
}
```