# How to change color of type Character (not String) in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

If I have a UILabel with a string like this:

```
func makeLabel() {
    textLabel.text = "3abc 3xyz apple3 3banana 3tree pluto3"
    textLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    ...
}
```

How can I change the color of just the "3" character? There are other questions here that look very similar but deal with string replacement, not character replacement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/2594560

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `textLabel.attributedText` instead of `textLabel.text`

To see how NSAttributedText works: read [the documentation of NSAttributedText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring) or [this stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/2594560)

So a possible solution is to iterate over all the characters in your string and to a add red foreground color if the character is "3"

**Swift 3**:

```
textLabel.attributedText = "3ab apple3 3bana".characters.reduce(NSMutableAttributedString()) {
    $0.append(
        NSAttributedString(
            string: String($1),
            attributes: [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: $1 == "3" ? UIColor.red : .black
            ]
        )
    )
    return $0
}
```

**Swift 4**:

```
textLabel.attributedText = "3ab apple3 3bana".reduce(NSMutableAttributedString()) {
    $0.append(
        NSAttributedString(
            string: String($1),
            attributes: [
                .foregroundColor: $1 == "3" ? UIColor.red : .black
            ]
        )
    )
    return $0
}
```

## Not a duplicate

I think this is not a duplicate of [Color all occurrences of string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180184/color-all-occurrences-of-string-in-swift) because **Strings** and **Characters** are two different things in Swift!

Comment: Furthermore, that question was asked 2 years ago in Objective-C (albeit with a Swift 3 update) while yours is in Swift 4.

Comment: I get the error that value type string has no member "reduce".

Comment: I tested this code in Xcode 9 beta-5 and it works fine. You are probably using Swift 3 where a String is not a collection and has no reduce method. Which swift toolchain do you use? And in which version of Xcode?

Comment: That's why then. I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 so I'm still in Swift 3.

Comment: I'll add a Swift 3 version to the answer

Comment: You are kind of a big deal right now.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered when it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use this extension:

```
extension UILabel {

    func setText(_ text: String, withColorPart colorTextPart: String, color: UIColor) {
        attributedText = nil
        let result =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        result.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: NSString(string: text.lowercased()).range(of: colorTextPart.lowercased()))
        attributedText = result
    }

}
```

Example:

```
let label = UILabel()

label.setText("3abc 3xyz apple3 3banana 3tree pluto3", withColorPart: "3", color: .red)
```

Comment: Well that example only colors the first "3" character