# Swift 4 array issue in changing text colour

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a string and I want to change colors of two words in that string. So, I created a function

```
func setup()
    {

        let main_string = "By continuing you agree to our Term of use and Privacy Policy "

        var string_to_color = ["By continuing you agree to our","and"]

        for i in 0..<2
        {

            let range = (main_string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color[i])

            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string:main_string)

            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black , range: range)

            privacyL.attributedText = attributedString

        }
```

But, it only changes the colour for the second word and not for the first one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Alors, you are doing a for loop, but overriding each time `privacyL.attributedText`. Note that `range(of:)` returns only FIRST occurence found, so if `main_string` was `"and and"`, only first one would be colored.

Comment: Yeah, so what can I do to colour the second and in "and and"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let main_string = "By continuing you agree to our Term of use and Privacy Policy "

var string_to_color = ["By continuing you agree to our","and"]

for i in 0..<2
{

    let range = (main_string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color[i])

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string:main_string)

    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black , range: range)

    privacyL.attributedText = attributedString

}
```

You are overriding each time `privacyL.attributedText`, so you'll get only the "result" of last iteration.

Instead, do:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string:main_string)
for i in 0..<2
{
    let range = (main_string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color[i])
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black , range: range)

}
privacyL.attributedText = attributedString
```

Now, next issues:
Don't do a loop `for i in 0..<2`, instead use at least the `count` of `string_to_color` (or a [for each loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121)). If tomorrow you add a string in it or remove one, you'll encounter an issue.

Also `range(of:)` will return the first occurence found, so if you have:

```
let main_string = "and and"
var string_to_color = ["something", "and"]
```

only the first "and" will be colored.

You have then to iterate or use a `NSRegularExpression`.
Here is a related question: [Color all occurrences of string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180184/color-all-occurrences-of-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to Larme's answer. You can create extension of `String`, which will be responsible for string coloring

```
extension String {
    func colored(_ strings: [String], with color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        for string in strings {
            let range = (self as NSString).range(of: string)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color , range: range)
        }
        return attributedString
    }
}
```

And now you can use it anywhere in your code, like this:

```
let main_string = "By continuing you agree to our Term of use and Privacy Policy "
let string_to_color = ["By continuing you agree to our","and"]
privacyL.attributedText = main_string.colored(string_to_color, with: UIColor.red)
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. Suppose, I want to make the first "and" in "and and" as a link, what can I do?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Taras.